# Аккаунт разработчика

Tags: android, google-play, apple, google-account

вопрос у владельцев аккаунта разработчика Google Android или Apple. Доделываю свой проект для Андройда, хочу использовать там платный контент и монетизацию. Я физ.лицо, вопрос, нужно ли открывать ИП по закону?

Comment: Нет, можно как физик издавать.

Comment: Это точно?просто надо ж налог какой то

Comment: В конце года заполнять налоговую декларацию.

Comment: Но и деньги тогда выводить в конце года?)просто по логике вывод денег из за рубежа на карту, наверное отслеживается?

Comment: Отслеживается. Да нет, можно каждый месяц. Главное в конце года декларацию подать.

Comment: А можете пож_та по конкретнее, как этот принцип подачи декларации называется?Это на подобии Авторского вознаграждения или как?

Comment: Я не силён в этом, мы как юрики работаем.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится к программированию

Answer (score 1):

По закону: нужно сдавать годовую налоговую декларацию, в которой будет отчет о полученном доходе.

По факту, насколько я знаю, доход менее 600 000 рублей в месяц банки отслеживают только в "ручном режиме". То есть, только если кто-то специально заинтересуется - будут вопросы, где 13% государству? И штраф.

ИП для продажи контента открывать не надо, такие продажи считаются "авторскими отчислениями" (как будто вам издательство платит за книгу). То есть под статью о "Незаконной предпринимательской деятельности" вы не попадёте.

Если вы получаете доход с рекламы, то ИП, да, нужно.